# On Linux, is there a program to arrange text and images freely on a canvas for note taking purposes?

Tags: linux, note-taking, plain-text, mind-mapping

My typical use scenario is that I am researching a topic and want to save one or two images per article together with a text summary of that article. I wish to arrange these spatially by pasting images and text into a canvas so that I can get an overview of the topic and recall information by viewing the images.

Back when I ran Windows, I used `OneNote` for this purpose since it lets you type text and insert images anywhere, not only linearly. What I did not like was that it organized my notes for me in notebooks. I would like to use my folder hierarchy to sort notes together with other files relevant to each project. I take most short notes in markdown, but for larger notes (e.g. literature review), I like organizing images and text snippets visually on a canvas (preferably endless).

The most suitable software I have found so far are mind mapping programs like `xmind` (runs a little sluggish) and `freeplane` (got that classic alien java look, but seems quite capable). I would like the software to run locally, rather than being cloud based. Bonus points if it saves files as plain text.

Is there anything more suitable that I have overlooked? Should I keep exploring mindmapping software or is there another category altogether that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at [RedNotebook](http://rednotebook.sourceforge.net/).

- Linux - **Yes** *and Windows/OS-X*
- Free - Gratis & FOSS
- Plain Text **Yes** data is stored as plain text, archived to zip and exportable to PDF, HTML, Latex
- Data stored locally **Yes** *if you need to have remote access simply store the data in your Dropbox or Google Drive folder*
- Multiple Notebooks **Yes**
- Also has the ability to use and create templates for specific tasks/entry types.

The only thing that it lacks compared to mind mapping is that is does tend to organise things linearly.

Comment: Thanks, RedNotebook seems like a great alternative for many OneNote users. However, since it lacks the ability to arrange text and images freely on a canvas, it is not really an alternative in my case. When I tested it out, it also seemed to me that it keeps all notes within a notebook which is uses for organization, rather than using the file system as the organizational system and then opening single notes from folders. I clarified my question.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I keep exploring mindmapping software or is there another category altogether that I am not aware of?

Would by any chance [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) work for you?

Pros:

- Mature, professional,
- GTK native (no aliens! ;))
- F/OSS,
- uses SVG as native format - that could partially fulfill the 'plain text'
  requirements,
- any graphics (yeah it's graphics software),
- Linux, Windows,
- awesome [documentation](https://inkscape.org/en/learn/) with tutorials (albeit you may not need all
  the stuff in your case),
- [addons](https://inkscape.org/en/download/addons/) in any language,
- CLI (`man inkscape`!)

Challenges:

- I'm not sure how easy is to just arbitrarily add text that you don't
  plan to style anyhow.
- Data stored as files, that is, you are the boss of the hierarchy,
  but it may be inconvenient if you need to frequently switch between
  notes or want to re-ogranize the hierarchy often

  This is however something that can be addressed by proper choice
  and use of window and file managers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was trying out Inkscape initially, but found the mindmap oriented software easier in terms of adding and formatting text. For other purposes, Inkscape is indeed a solid choices for many of the reasons you mentioned, but it is not ideal for my purpose.

Earlier, I have also taken a look at some diagramming software, as you suggest in your other answer, but have yet to find one that is better than freeplane or xmind.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I keep exploring mindmapping software or is there another category altogether that I am not aware of?

Related category worth checking out is software specifically written for [drawing diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagramming_software).

(Unfortunately my favorite one--[Dia](http://dia-installer.de/index.html.en), does not seem to support adding bitmap graphics, or at least not in such arbitrary manner...)

Answer (score 0):

For Linux there is something similar to OneNote. This is a **Joplin** app.
It has pretty decent functionality, similar to OneNote. There are both mobile and desktop versions, as well as synchronization.